# What does "word + っちゃ/といえば word" mean?

Tags: grammar

Things like 好きっちゃ好きかも、大変っちゃ大変なんですけど、仕方がないっちゃ仕方がない, what does it mean?

Comment: These should answer your question [Meaning of a pattern "AといえばAにも見える"](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/64800/meaning-of-a-pattern-a%e3%81%a8%e3%81%84%e3%81%88%e3%81%b0a%e3%81%ab%e3%82%82%e8%a6%8b%e3%81%88%e3%82%8b) [The nuances between といえば, というと and といったら](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/88857/45489)